# React js updating boolean state of unknown number of data

Tags: reactjs

I have one collapse menu that is hard-coded. I'm controlling whether it's open or closed using a single state `surveysOpen`:

```
        <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <FolderIcon sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }} />
          </ListItemIcon>

          <ListItemText primary='All surveys' />

          {surveysOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItemButton>
        <Collapse in={surveysOpen} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
          {isSurveysLoading || isSurveysRefetching ? (
            <LoadingProgress inSidebar />
          ) : isAdmin ? (
            adminContent
          ) : (
            clientContent
          )}
        </Collapse>
```

Now the problem is, I will have data coming from an API. I want to render the above code for each item.

I obviously can't create a `useState` for each one because I don't know how many there is (if any)

```
const [surveysOpen, setSurveysOpen] = useState(false);
```

How do I control whether each one is opened or closed?

```
{surveysOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
```

Is there a dynamic way to update the state of unknown # of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this. The first, and the one I consider the best is to make each Survey its own component, and let it track the open/close state for itself.

The second solution, which will may be easier to implement is to keep it the way you're doing it, and just track it using key-value pairs:

```
const [openMap, setOpenMap] = useState(new Map());

onSurveysLoaded = (surveys) => {
   ...
   openMap.set(..., ...);
   setOpenMap(new Map(openMap));
};

...

surveyIsOpen = openMap.get(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the answer. I will consider the first approach as it may make my main component less cluttered.